# Would the angle theta made during instantaneous speed is always same or not?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

[image]

I hope you can understand that I am talking about instantaneous speed here.You can notice I have done summation of all small ds/dt in my photo.

The angle which I have got it theta.I want to know is whether this angle theta is going to always remain same for those ds or not.

How would it affect the answers if it does or not be same value of theta for all the ds ?

Answer (score 0):

It will change as you can see the slope of the curve is changing.

Comment: Does it have any effect on summation of ds that we do

Comment: @Aridhan I dont understand the question.

Comment: As theta is changing right

Comment: Also tan theta must be different

Comment: Does that have any effect on summation of ds.

Comment: I was thinking , if velocity of body is constant , I thought then we can simply do n (ds) = s. And if it accelerates, then it will be ds1 + ds2 + ds3..

Comment: @Aridhan velocity is ds/dt. You don't need to sum the ds. Yes tan($\theta$) is different hence velocity is different.

Comment: It says in my book by summing ds.we get s

Comment: For graph  which have slope

Comment: For which have a parabola

Comment: @Aridhan  but you are finding velocity.

Answer (score 0):

You cant randomly do summation for curves. Consider this path

To know ds/dt I.e slope of a curve you must differentiate
[image]

$ds/dt=2x$   here y coordinate is displacement and x axis is for time

For summation you'll have to integrate I dont know if you have studied it or not

Comment: I am studying it.Not done